# Compare the values of two dictionarie in Python and return the key for the values with a difference bigger than 2

Tags: python

So, I have two dictionary files in binary, and I need to compare the values between them.
The keys have the same name, but the values differ.
I managed to read them and turn the values into integers, but now I want to compare the value from the first dictionary with the value from the second dictionary and only print or return the key that have a difference between values of min 2.

I tried using this code, but I only get the keys that are different in values, but I don't want the ones with a difference lower than 2.

````
    for key in primary:
        if (key in secondary and primary[key] != secondary[key]):
            faulty_sensors_values[key] = primary[key]
    print(faulty_sensors_values)```
````

Comment: Please add sample data for both dictionaries

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
a = {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 8}
b = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3}

for x,y in zip(a,b):
    if ((a[x]-b[y])>2):
        print(x)
```

Will print:

```
b
c
```

Comment: If ```(a[x]-b[y])>2``` then isn't ```(a[x] != b[y])``` implied?

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in primary:
        if (key in secondary and abs(primary[key]-secondary[key]) >= 2):
            faulty_sensors_values[key] = primary[key]
    print(faulty_sensors_values)
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works, but I also need  to return even if the value from the secondary is higher by 2 than the one in the primary. I iterate through secondary and use the if you gave but changing the primary with secondary and I only get the first key from the first dictionary with a changed value and the first key from the second dictionary with a changed value. I need it to give me all the keys from both dictionaries that have a difference bigger than 2 between them. Thanks!

Comment: use abs(primary[key]-secondary[key]) >= 2 if any one of the primary or secondary can be greater.